# How to add default login page for existing angular website

Tags: angular

I've ready template of angular 6 ,i need to add default consumer_login page

tried creating component of consumer and given path in routers

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'consumer',
  pathMatch: 'full',
}, {
  path: 'admin-layout',
  component: AdminLayoutComponent,
  canDeactivate: [AuthGuard]
  children: [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
  }]
}
```

I expect on running Ng serve, the default page need to be consumer_login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new default login page is quite simple and for that I usually do the following steps:

1) **Create the login page** component (I called LoginPage);

2) **Routing file**: add the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginPage, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPage },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminPage, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] }
];
```

This means the root path (first instruction) and '/login' will redirect to LoginPage and in the third route option we see that when we try to access /admin page it will check if the component can be activated or not.

**IMPORTANT**: All routes that doesn't need authentication to be accessed (Login, Contact, AboutUs, etc), don't use the property "canActivate".

3) **AuthenticationGuard**: This is where you check if you are authenticated or not (boolean return)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { Page, RouterService } from '../service-tools/router.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private router:RouterService) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated){
       // log or display a message saying that the access to the page requires authentication
    }
    else
      return true;
  }
}
```

4) **AuthenticationService**: Because we need to store somewhere the authentication state, I've created a service that is used both by the Guard and LoginPage. I will make it simpler here but it will require some business logic like calling an API or something like that. Also, it depends if you will be using a third part component like OAuth or not (not described in your question, so I will skip this).

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OperationResult } from '../model/operation-result.model';
import { RouterService, Page } from '../service-tools/router.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private user: UserSimplified; // just an example to show that we can use a model to do that

  constructor(private router: RouterService) { }

  public authenticate(userName: string, password: string): Subscription {

    // do the API call
    // store the result or return a subscription to do it

  }

  public get currentUser(): UserSimplified {    
    if (!this.user){
      // here you can get the user from local storage for example (save it during the api call)
      // this.user = JSON.parse(this.getString('currentUser')) as UserSimplified;
    }
    return this.user;
  }

  public get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return (this.currentUser != null);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    // clear the localStorage user data
  }
}
```

5) **LoginPage**: I've used a standard HTML login page (userName, pwd, login, cancel). LoginButton click calls the authenticate method of the LoginPage that subscribes to AuthenticationService.authenticate() which when completed returns success or a message.

```
  public authenticate(): void {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.authService.authenticate(this.userName, this.pwd).add(response => {
        if (response.success){
            this.router.navigate([ROUTE_NAME, EVENTUAL_PARAMETER]); // route name would be admin, for example
        } else {
            // display a message, log or do something with the result
        }
  }
```

That's what I usually do. Hope it helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can set your consumer_login page as your default home page like so.

```
...
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/consumer_login', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'consumer_login',   component: ConsumerLoginComponent},
...
```

Comment: actually that template have two routing.ts i.e.(app.routing.ts and admin-layout.routing.ts), where i need to include this path\

Comment: Must be in your primary module's routing which is app.routing.ts